# Determining time it takes a downward-moving animation to reach a spot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have animated an image to drop straight from the top of the screen to the bottom and I want to be able to determine the time it takes for the image to reach a certain point on the screen. Normally, this would be easy to do by multiplying the y-coordinate of the point you want by the duration of the animation, and then dividing it by the total amount of 'pixels' your image moves from start to finish. However, objective-c animations start off slowly, accelerate, and then decelerate before stopping--which means I cannot use this method to calculate the time it takes. So is there any way I can determining time it takes a downward-moving animation to reach a spot?

Edit: With animations, supposedly there's no way of determining the point of an object at any point during the animation--the only information available, which you provide, is the beginning point and end point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using  `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` you can set the `options` parameter to `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`. The default has a funky curve but `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` is just what it sounds like; linear. No speed ups, no speed downs. Also, yes, there is a way to access the location of the animated view. You access its presentation layer (the layer used to present animations) and use *its* frame's position.

EDIT: Here's an example of block based animation that computes the distance from a view to the destination using the Pythagorean theorem and animates the view to the destination with a linear curve.

```
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGPoint destination = CGPointZero;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: sqrt(pow(view.frame.origin.x - destination.x, 2) + pow(view.frame.origin.y - destination.y, 2)) / pixelsPerSecondVelocity
                          delay: 0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^(void) {
                         view.frame = CGRectMake(destination.x,destination.y,view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // nothing
                     }];
```

If you are targeting below iOS 4 you can just add the code below after the `begin` but before the `commit`.

```
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
```

Comment: Ah, it would be nice to make it linear. But all I'm using is this: [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(appleView)];. I guess what you're talking about is Core Animation, whereas mine is only UIImageView animation. Perhaps I should use CA instead..thank you!

Comment: @user1824518 Both are used the same way. The only difference is that one uses `begin` and `commit`, which is discouraged after iOS 4 (but required before iOS 4). The new way is block-based animation. I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help and information. I'm targeting above iOS 4 so I'll work with the block based animation code. Thanks again!